# Failed to execute child

Tags: linux, fedora, xfce

When I try to run Terminal (Fedora 26, xfce) I get error:

[image]

If I click "window-close", I see it:

[image]

Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+X, and any combinations doesn't work! (STDIN doesn't work)

---

Can open another Emulator and run `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator  /usr/bin/node` - then Terminal works.

[image]

---

How I can solve it?

Comment: What is the command line of the shortcut you are using to launch the terminal? What happens if you press ALTF+F2 and type `xfce4-terminal`?

Comment: I guess you set the shell command of xfce4-terminal but you set it as empty string, huh?

Comment: It would be useful to know the command you use to run the Terminal.

Comment: @RalfFriedl, see my screen-cast: https://youtu.be/udeT8K6U0PU

Comment: @giusti, same error!

Comment: I saw your screen-cast, but it doesn't show what is called. What is the command that is run by your menu entry? You seem to have a way to start a terminal with a shell, why don't you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve:

Open terminal -> Edit -> Preferences

and in line "Custom command" write `/usr/bin/bash`